# jhipster 5 how can I access an entity without getting the login modal?

Tags: jhipster

I have my post entity that it is open from the SecurityConfig so I can access to it without login, but Jhipster keeps on bringing the login model (and I just want to show it if the user tries to create a comment). Does it has anything to do with the canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService] in the post.route.ts file?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { JhiDataUtils } from 'ng-jhipster';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { DATE_TIME_FORMAT } from 'app/shared/constants/input.constants';
import { ITEMS_PER_PAGE } from 'app/shared';
import { JhiEventManager, JhiParseLinks, JhiAlertService } from 'ng-jhipster';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Principal } from 'app/core';

import { IComment } from 'app/shared/model/comment.model';
import { CommentService } from 'app/entities/comment';
import { IPost } from 'app/shared/model/post.model';
import { PostService } from 'app/entities/post';
import { IProfile } from 'app/shared/model/profile.model';
import { ProfileService } from 'app/entities/profile';

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-post-detail',
    templateUrl: './post-detail.component.html'
})
export class PostDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    id: any;
    private _comment: IComment;
    isSaving: boolean;

    post: any;
    posts: IPost[];

    profile: IProfile;
    profiles: IProfile[];

    currentAccount: any;
    creationDate: string;

    comments: IComment[];
    error: any;
    success: any;
    eventSubscriber: Subscription;
    routeData: any;
    links: any;
    totalItems: any;
    queryCount: any;
    itemsPerPage: any;
    page: any = 1;
    predicate: any = 'id';
    previousPage: any = 0;
    reverse: any = 'asc';

    constructor(
        private dataUtils: JhiDataUtils,
        private parseLinks: JhiParseLinks,
        private jhiAlertService: JhiAlertService,
        private commentService: CommentService,
        private postService: PostService,
        private principal: Principal,
        private profileService: ProfileService,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private eventManager: JhiEventManager
    ) {
        this.itemsPerPage = ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
        this.routeData = this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
            this.page = 0;
            this.previousPage = 0;
            this.reverse = false;
            this.predicate = 'id';
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('CONSOLOG: M:ngOnInit & O: this.page : ', this.page);
        console.log('CONSOLOG: M:ngOnInit & O: this.predicate : ', this.predicate);
        console.log('CONSOLOG: M:ngOnInit & O: this.previousPage : ', this.previousPage);
        console.log('CONSOLOG: M:ngOnInit & O: this.reverse : ', this.reverse);
        this.isSaving = false;
        this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ post }) => {
            this.post = post;
            console.log('CONSOLOG: M:ngOnInit & O: this.post : ', this.post);
        });
        this.loadAll();
        this.principal.identity().then(account => {
            this.currentAccount = account;
        });
        this.comment = new Object();
        this.comment.commentText = '';
        this.registerChangeInComments();
    }

    saveComment() {
        this.isSaving = true;
        this.comment.creationDate = moment(this.creationDate, DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
        if (this.comment.id !== undefined) {
            this.subscribeToSaveResponse(this.commentService.update(this.comment));
        } else {
            this.comment.postId = this.post.id;
            this.loggedProfile()
            .subscribe(
                    (res: HttpResponse<IProfile[]>) => {
                        this.profiles = res.body;
                        this.comment.profileId = this.profiles[0].id;
                        this.comment.isOffensive = false;
      this.subscribeToSaveResponse(this.commentService.create(this.comment));
                    },
                    (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
            );
        }
    }

    private loggedProfile() {
        const query = {
            };
        if ( this.currentAccount.id  != null) {
            query['userId.equals'] = this.currentAccount.id;
        }
        return this.profileService
            .query(query);
    }

    private subscribeToSaveResponse(result: Observable<HttpResponse<IComment>>) {
        result.subscribe((res: HttpResponse<IComment>) => this.onSaveSuccess(), (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onSaveError());
    }

    private onSaveSuccess() {
        this.isSaving = false;
        this.reload();
    }

    private onSaveError() {
        this.isSaving = false;
    }

    private onError(errorMessage: string) {
        this.jhiAlertService.error(errorMessage, null, null);
    }

    trackPostById(index: number, item: IPost) {
        return item.id;
    }

    trackProfileById(index: number, item: IProfile) {
        return item.id;
    }

    get comment() {
        return this._comment;
    }

    set comment(comment: IComment) {
        this._comment = comment;
        this.creationDate = moment(comment.creationDate).format(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
    }

    byteSize(field) {
        return this.dataUtils.byteSize(field);
    }

    openFile(contentType, field) {
        return this.dataUtils.openFile(contentType, field);
    }

    previousState() {
        window.history.back();
    }

    reload() {
        window.location.reload();
    }

    loadPage(page) {
        this.previousPage = page;
        this.page = page;
        this.loadAll();
    }

    loadAll() {
        const query = {
                page: this.page - 1,
                size: this.itemsPerPage,
                sort: this.sort()
            };
            query['postId.equals'] = this.post.id;
        this.commentService
            .query(query)
            .subscribe(
                (res: HttpResponse<IComment[]>) => {
                    console.log('CONSOLOG: M:loadAll & O: query : ', query);
                    this.paginateComments(res.body, res.headers);
                },
                (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
            );
    }

    transition() {
        this.loadAll();
    }

    clear() {
        this.page = 0;
        this.router.navigate([
            '/comment',
            {
                page: this.page,
                sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')
            }
        ]);
        this.loadAll();
    }

    trackId(index: number, item: IComment) {
        return item.id;
    }

    registerChangeInComments() {
        this.eventSubscriber = this.eventManager.subscribe('commentListModification', response => this.loadAll());
    }

    sort() {
        const result = [this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')];
        if (this.predicate !== 'id') {
            result.push('id');
        }
        return result;
    }

    private paginateComments(data: IComment[], headers: HttpHeaders) {
        this.links = this.parseLinks.parse(headers.get('link'));
        this.totalItems = parseInt(headers.get('X-Total-Count'), 10);
        this.queryCount = this.totalItems;
        this.comments = data;
    }
}
```

and here is the SecurityConfig:

```
package com.jhipsterpress.web.config;

import com.jhipsterpress.web.security.*;

import io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties;
import io.github.jhipster.security.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.RememberMeServices;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import org.zalando.problem.spring.web.advice.security.SecurityProblemSupport;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    private final RememberMeServices rememberMeServices;

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;

    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;

    public SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder, UserDetailsService userDetailsService, 
        JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties, RememberMeServices rememberMeServices, CorsFilter corsFilter, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport) {
        this.authenticationManagerBuilder = authenticationManagerBuilder;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
        this.rememberMeServices = rememberMeServices;
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("Security configuration failed", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        return new AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/content/**")
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
            .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
        .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
            .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
            .key(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getRememberMe().getKey())
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/api/authentication")
            .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
            .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .usernameParameter("j_username")
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN);

    }
}
```

I have played with most parts of the canActivate, but still does not work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you add your security config codes?

Comment: There it is! Thanks for looking at it

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the UserRouteAccessService line in the post.route.ts file?

Comment: Where did you permit post entity to access without authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Jon, was right. Without the authorities and commenting out the canActivate it works.

```
{
    path: 'post/:id/view',
    component: PostDetailComponent,
    resolve: {
        post: PostResolve
    },
    data: {
        authorities: [],
        pageTitle: 'jhipsterpressApp.post.home.title'
    },
//        canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
},
```